# Why adding a node to a doubly linked list deletes all nodes except first node?

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm using double linked list for keeping 4 different records in c.

I'm having trouble while creating space for doubly linked list. When I try to add more than 2 nodes, I lose all nodes except the first node and I'm seeing data of first and last nodes. I can't see the nodes from 2nd to last. I tried changing links between nodes but it didn't work. Here is my code;

```
struct node {
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    char roll[100];
    char department[100];
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct node *first_oto = NULL, *last_oto = NULL, *l;

 void insert() {
     int i, counter = 1;

     first_oto = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     first_oto->prev = NULL;
     first_oto->next = NULL;

     printf(" %d- Name:", counter);
     scanf("%s", first_oto->name);
     printf(" %d-Surname", counter);
     scanf("%s", first_oto->surname);
     printf(" %d-Number", counter);
     scanf("%s", first_oto->roll);
     printf(" %d-Department", counter);
     scanf("%s", first_oto->department);
     first_oto->next = NULL;

     for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
         counter++;

         l = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

         printf(" %d-Name:", counter);
         scanf("%s", l->name);
         printf(" %d-Surname:", counter);
         scanf("%s", l->surname);
         printf(" %d-Number:", counter);
         scanf("%s", l->roll);
         printf(" %d-Department:", counter);
         scanf("%s", l->department);
         printf("\n");

         l->next = NULL;
         l->prev = first_oto;
         first_oto->next = l;
    }
```

In first part of the insert function my code is taking records of first nodes. While my program operates for loop it takes other nodes but adds only final node. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Does that even compile? What do you think `counter+` does?

Comment: `first_oto->next=l;` wipes out the previous value of `first_oto->next`

Comment: it seems like all your last node's previous node is the first node, not the node created previously.

Comment: [choir bellows:] You don't need to, and probably shouldn't, cast the result of `malloc` in C

Comment: `struct otomata` ??

Comment: In  addition to the mysterious `otomata`, what  is `l`, and why haven't you included its declaration? Does this code even compile? Is this really what you're using? How? Where's the rest of it?

Comment: Now what is this : `...  = NULL, *l;`

Comment: You don't seem to be maintaining `last_oto` at all; you initialize it to null, but that's all.  It doesn't matter too much at the moment, but why bother with the variable if you're not going to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a temporary variable for adding situation.

```
     struct node *temp;
```

In for loop after assigning `l->next=NULL` We have to add some code particles for temp. We keep first element as temp and we use temp variable to not to lose data.

In the code below we do it.

```
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = first_oto;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = l;
    l->prev = temp;
    last_oto = l;
```

The problem is solved after writing this lines.

Answer (score 0):

The code that adds elements to the list is incomplete.

```
    l->next=NULL;
    l->prev=first_oto;
    first_oto->next=l;
    /* There's another thing you need to do right here. */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
void insert(void)
{
    struct node *new_node, *temp;
    char ans = 'y';
    int pos;
    do {
        traverse();
        printf("Enter the element :\n");
        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d", &new_node->info);
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        if (start == NULL) {
            start = new_node;
            current = new_node; 
        } else {
            printf("Enter the position at which u wanna enter : (1-%d)\n", count + 1);
            scanf("%d", &pos);
            if (pos == 1) {
                start->prev = new_node;
                new_node->next = start;
                start = new_node;
            } else
            if (pos == count + 1) {
                current->next = new_node;
                new_node->prev = current;
                current = new_node;
            } else {
                int i = 0;  
                temp = start;
                while (i < pos - 2) {
                    temp = temp->next;
                    i++;
                }
                new_node->prev = temp;
                new_node->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = new_node;
            }
        }
        printf("Wanna enter more ??\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);
    } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: Try to not use answers like 'try this'. Good answer should provide a complete solution (with description if it's possible and necessary).